# Python: Checking parameter names against kwarg keys

Tags: python, keyword-argument

sorry for the naive question, but when executing this code:

```
def test_kwargs(n, **kwargs):  
    if kwargs is None:  
        print("no keyword args")  
        return  
    for key, value in kwargs.items():  
        print(str(key))  
        print(str(value))  
        if key==fn:
            print(value(10))  

test_kwargs(3,fn=lambda x: x^2)
```

I get an error in the check

```
if key==fn
```

NameError: **name 'fn' is not defined**

However *print(str(key))* correctly outputs 'fn'.

So what is going on here; why does the test fail and how can the key be checked against possible argument names?

Comment: `**kwargs` becomes a dictionary. So `kwargs['fn']` will contain your lambda function.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman as you may have noticed I have assigned kwarg['fn'] to value and can invoke the lambda funktion; so that is not the problem. I would appeciate an answer to the question, namely why the equality test fails and not some unrelated trivia.

Comment: The equality test fails because `fn` is not something you've defined. When you call your function with a keyword argument, it's put in the dictionary `kwargs` and is accessible through `kwargs['fn']`. I.e. you'll have to check if the keywords exist in `kwargs` as you would any other dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kwargs` is a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are those values passed in. You can pull a particular kwarg out by the string key used to pass it:

```
if "fn" in kwargs:
    fn = kwargs["fn"]
```

You can also do this:

```
fn = kwargs.get("fn")
if fn is not None:
    ... # do something with `fn`
```

Answer (score 1):

The `key` is a string of the key name you pass so you have to compare it with another string.

It should be:

```
if key=="fn":
    print(value(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

### The type of args and kwargs

As you can see, **args** is a **tuple** and **kwargs** is a **dictionary**.

```py
def test_kwargs2(*args, **kwargs):
    print(type(args))
    print(type(kwargs))


test_kwargs2(1, 2, 3, 4, a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

**Output**

```
<class 'tuple'>
<class 'dict'>
```

In the [django-3.8](/questions/tagged/django-3.8) you can use [**Assignment expressions(the walrus operator)**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

```py
def test_kwargs(n, **kwargs):
    if func := kwargs.get('fn'): # like dict
        print(func(n))


test_kwargs(3, fn=lambda x: x ^ 2)
test_kwargs(3)
```

**Output:**

```
1
```